# Data throughput capability of GHS integrity and QNX rtos's

Tags: rtos

I am evaluating two RTOS's (GHS Integrity, QNX) based on few high level requirements. One of the requirement is the capability of the RTOS to handle high data throughput in terms of inter process communications(through shared memory) and also through network stack(>10GBPS). Since these are proprietary RTOS, it is hard to get access to them without buying. Any comments on the performance of the two RTOS's will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Anup

Comment: Given that these are both proprietary, have you contacted the vendors to ask if they can give you performance metrics? A lot of what you described is also going to depend on your hardware.

Comment: Totally agree about the dependency on the underlying hardware. Just wanted to know from a high level if anyone who has used those RTOS's(especially GHS integrity). Yes, and have not got a convincing response

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter little early. Yes, I have contacted the vendors for those numbers and have not got a convincing response.